# Let $p\left(x\right)=x^{2}+bx+c=0$ and equation $p\left(p\left(p\left(x\right)\right)\right)=0$ have a common root then:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, roots

1. prove that equations $p(p(p(x)))=0$ and $p(p(p(p(p(x)))))=0$ have at least two common roots.
2. prove that $p(p(p(p(p(p(x))))))=0$ has $0$ as a root.

How do i go about solving these problems, what's the concept behind it? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a$ is the common root for the first two polynomials. It follows that $0=p(p(p(a)))=p(p(0))=p^2(0)$ where, for brevity, we denote by $p^n(x)$ the $n$th step composition of $p$. Thus, for any even $n$, $p^n(0)=p^{n-2}(p^2(0))=p^{n-2}(0)$. Induction shows that $0$ is now a root of $p^n(x)$ for all $n\in 2\Bbb N$. Now apply this trick with $a$ instead of $0$ for odd $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i did not understand from 3rd line onwards, how does $p^{2}\left(0\right)$ translate to $p^{n}\left(0\right)$. Sorry, I'm a bit new to high school mathematics, so i don't know about induction.

Comment: Suppose $n=4$, then $p^4(0)=p^2(p^2(0))=p^2(0)=0$. Now apply $p^2$ to $p^4(0)=0$ and you will find $p^6(0)=0$. As you can see, you can keep doing this as many times as you want, everytime increasing the composition by 2. Induction is just the formalized idea that lets you say "this statement holds for all even $n$". In your case, you do not need induction, as your problem 2 just asks about $p^6$, but if it were asking about $p^{1000}$, in principle, you could repeat the previous argument until you showed $p^{1000}(0)=0$.